# How to use operator "is" with Nullable

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

I want to use the "is" operator to unwrap Nullable. Something like:

```
if(nullable is not null notNullValue)
    notNullValue.ToString();
```

The workaround I'm using:

```
if(value is SomeType notNullValue)
    notNullValue.ToString();
```

Using an additional variable in this case is ugly:

```
class Sample {
    public Enum? Get() {...}
}
data.Select(x => (Sample)x)
    .Where(x => x.Get() is Enum enumValue ? StrictCheck(enumValue) : false)
    .Select(...)
    .ToArray();
```

Is there no way not to re-write the type?

Comment: Note, the C# 7.3 tag is important. The `nullable is not null notNullValue` syntax was added later, if memory serves. Before then, you could use `if (value is { } notNullValue)`

Comment: There is no "unwrapping". Just use `nullable` after the check. Which may be `is not null` or `!= null`.

Comment: `is not` is only available from C# 9.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns

Comment: I can't set version  9.0 due to outdated Winforms controls.

Comment: You can almost certainly use C# 9 (or even 10) anyway, by explicitly settting the `<LangVersion>` in the project file. Some features like default interface implementations need runtime support and can't work on Framework, but things like pattern matching are (AFAICT) fully supported (as in they work; obviously MS won't officially support using those language versions with older runtimes).

Comment: Note, your query can be written `data.Where(x => ((Sample)x).Get() is { } enumValue && StrictCheck(enumValue).Select(...).ToArray()`

Comment: Explicitly settting the `<LangVersion>` has no effect in my .Net Framework project

Comment: If it doesn't work you are likely using an old-style `.csproj` (not starting with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` at the top). Converting these to new-style is possible, but beyond the scope of this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the best solution:

```
    public static bool TryGetValue<T>(this T? nullable, out T value) where T : struct {
        if (nullable is T notNullValue) {
            value = notNullValue;
            return true;
        }
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
```